# How to count UP votes together and then select from database ORDER by UP votes

Tags: php, mysql, database, voting

I have voting system on my website, it stores each users vote in table called **skmp_voting** each record in this database has **id**, **item_id** (this is id of article user voted on), and **vote_value** .  vote_value depend's on what users did, if they voted up value is "1" if they voted down value is "-1".

I have toparticles.php page where I wan't to display top articles, so articles that have more up votes. Here is my mysql query to get top articles I have now:

```
SELECT stories.*, skmp_votes.vote_value FROM stories 
JOIN skmp_votes ON stories.id = skmp_votes.item_id 
ORDER BY skmp_votes.vote_value DESC
```

It select's article information from other table called **stories** and put's it against vote_value from **skmp_votes** table.

I'm pretty confident that this isn't right, as it selects vote_value that is equal to 1 or something, so I need to somehow count all vote_values together and then use mysql query to get top articles.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I think you should alter your scores to 1 and 0, not 1 and -1. A row in the table counts as a vote, but 1 equals up, and 0 equals down. The math gets funny when you add in negatives.

Comment: in this case would following query
"SELECT * FROM {$this->votes_table} WHERE `item_id`= $story_id AND `vote_value`<0";

Comment: look like this instead

"SELECT * FROM {$this->votes_table} WHERE `item_id`= $story_id AND `vote_value`=0";

not sure where to add one = sign or two ==

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I can't change -1 to zero as I need it like that for another thing on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your voting table. As I imagined, it has a row for each vote. In this case, you'll have to do a sum for the votes wich match an article. i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM skmp_voting WHERE item_id='$article_id';
```

You use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` becouse you want to substract the value from the negative votes.

EDIT: complementing the answer

This following Query will get you every article and its total votes, ordered by the total votes (the most voted articles at the top)

```
SELECT stories.*, SUM(skmp_votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories 
  JOIN skmp_votes ON stories.id = skmp_votes.item_id 
  ORDER BY skmp_votes.total_votes DESC
```

To get, say the 5 most voted articles, you just add at the end `LIMIT 5`

Comment: Gives an error, it work's fine with initial query, but when I added your one it did not display any articles and gave warring. ((( Please Tell me if you need any additional info on my database structure to help

Comment: what's the warning? I just cought it. in <code>ORDER BY skmp_votes.total_votes DESC</code> total_votes is an artificial column, wich does not exist in skmp_votes. change that line for <code>ORDER BY total_votes DESC</code>

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't seem to work either, it only shows one record that is not even top rated, I think the issue is with 1 and -1 values I use for votes, but I can't change -1 value to 0 or anything else, because I need it like that for another thing on the website, is there a way to modify this query to only sum UP votes? i.e. SUM skmp_votes.vote_value WHERE vote_value > 0 (I tried it like that, but id didn't work)

Comment: edit your initial post and add the structure of the votes tables.

Comment: try this:  SELECT stories.*, SUM(skmp_votes.vote_value) as 'total_votes' FROM stories 
  JOIN skmp_votes ON stories.id = skmp_votes.item_id GROUP BY stories.id ORDER BY skmp_votes.total_votes DESC

Comment: yep this last one seem's to work perfectly ))) just needed to changeORDER BY skmp_votes.total_votes to ORDER BY total_votes Thank you very much )))